# Adding columns to GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas

I would like to add columns `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` and I take coordinates from column 'geometry'. I have exemplary dataframe with 1 records. Where is the problem?

Data:

```
   FID_1        GODLO                                           geometry
0      0  7.101.01.21  POLYGON ((7340000.000 5425000.000, 7340000.000...
```

I use, but I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'Polygon' object does not support item assignment
```

```
import geopandas as gpd

budynki = gpd.read_file('/home/gis/siatki_skorowidzowe/s7_2000/2000s7_2000.shp', rows = slice(0,1), encoding ='cp1250')

xlist = []
ylist = []
for polygon in budynki['geometry']:
    for x, y in polygon.exterior.coords:
        xlist.append(x)
        ylist.append(y)
        for x in xlist:
            minx = float(min(xlist))
            maxx = float(max(xlist))
        for y in ylist:
            miny = float(min(ylist))
            maxy = float(max(ylist))
    polygon['xmin'] = minx
    polygon['xmax'] = maxx
    polygon['ymin'] = miny
    polygon['ymax'] = maxy
```

Comment: Perhaps change polygon['xmin'] = minx to budynki['xmin'] = minx as a start. Your 'polygon' variable is not a row of your dataframe, it's a shapely polygon. So you can't assign it columns. This will still not be right, though, as you haven't defined the 'xmin', 'xmax', etc columns in your dataframe. And which row of the dataframe should they go in? Your code needs to address that.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

`polygon` is a shapely geometry in your script, not a row. So you cannot add a key as in a dictionary or a column as in (geo)pandas (Geo)DataFrame.

Use this script.

```py
# other lines

def get_bounds(r):
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy =  r["geometry"].bounds    
    r["minx"] = minx
    r["miny"] = miny
    r["maxx"] = maxx
    r["maxy"] = maxy
    return r
    
budynki = budynki.apply(get_bounds, axis=1)
```